# where to download and refer to java auction examples?

Tags: java

I'm learning java and came across this website http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0-win/html-helpset/z400050692330.html, i wanted to download sample demos and source code, but not finding anywhere.

I think many of you have tried these, so please post a link to download those sample demos and source code.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the documentation page. So, all you've to do is find the `jme sdk`. See this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html) The documentation page details on `Getting started` and `Running sample code`. Read the prerequisites before installing. Also, consider @Taymon's advice.

Comment: yes i got it, this is mobile version of developing! The google lead me somewhere, i'll go back to proper java.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the Micro Edition of Java. If you're just learning Java, it is almost certainly not what you want; you are probably using Standard Edition.